# How to synchronise two NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, multithreading, core-data, nsoperation

I'm working on an ipad application that use coredata. It download information on a database that is on the web, and record them in coredata. The application is based on a split view. My problem was to make the download and the record of the data in background.
 Here is how I've done :
- I've create an NSOperation, that does the download and the record of the data.
- This NSOperation use a different NSManagedObjectContext than the context of the appDelegate, return by this function, that is in the appDelegate :

```
(NSManagedObjectContext*)newContextToMainStore {
     NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coord = nil;
     coord = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
     NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; 
     [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coord]; 
     return [moc autorelease];
}
```

- I've had an observer in the NSOperation, that will call this function in the appDelegate when I save the context, to modify the context of the delegate too :

```
- (void)mergeChangesFromContextSaveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
     [[self managedObjectContext]mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

But I've a problem, the synchronisation doesn't work, because the data on the rootViewController (that is a UITableViewController), that have a NSManagedObjectContext initialised with the context of the appDelegate and use as datasource a NSFetchedResultsController, don't actualise automatically the informations, as it normaly must do.
So I ask you : 
What did I do wrong ? Is it the good way to use two different context and synchonise them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here looks correct. You do want to make sure you implement the `NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate` methods in the rootViewController so the changes will appear in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate is implemented. In fact my system works when I launch it in the appDelegate, but not in an viewController called later. I'm looking for my mistake, I think it's just a little error...

Comment: Hi again, i'm confused, I've found my mistake : I've done two NSOperation subclass, and in the second, i've forgotten to add the observer to make the modification in the two context.
Thanks for your attention !